# How to determine the amount of cash acquired from the market or banks?

Tags: stocks, financial-statements

I'm trying to sum up the amount of dividend and the money acquired from financing activities, e.g lending from banks, or moneys from investors.

Then I can calculate the `Total Dividend / Total Acquired Money` ratio to determine whether the company has a good cashflow.

Now the problem is, I don't know how to sum up the "Total Acquired Money". Take Ford Motor as an example, I looked into the 10-K report: https://s201.q4cdn.com/693218008/files/doc_financials/2023/q4/Ford-2023-10-K-Report.pdf

Which one represents that value in the cash flow statements? It all looks to be paying the existing debt to me.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't "total acquired money" just be gross income? Or. If you just want sales, net income?Loans and such appear on both sides of the ledger, increasing cash on hand assets but also increasing liabilities. Ditto selling shares, I believe....

Comment: @keshlam My description might not be precise. I didn't mean money generated from sales, but money "borrowed" from banks or investors. I'm trying to use this method to determine how much money is "borrowed" and "given" to the investors or creditor.

Comment: The table you've given shows that, I think The "debt" lines cover borrowing and lending. The common stock line shows issuance/repurchase of shares, and the dividends line says how much outstanding shares cost the company in an ongoing basis. Am I missing something?